# Find the law of a random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

> Let $X$ be a discrete random value taking values in $\mathbb{N}^* = \left\{1, 2, 3, \ldots \right\}$, and such that $\exists p \in (0,1) \forall n \geq 1$:
>   $$
>  \mathbb{P}[X=n] = p \mathbb{P}[X \geq n]
> $$
>   Find the law of $X$.

I understood the definition of law of random variable but I have problem to apply it in specific case as this one, can someone help me?

Comment: Hint: $\sum\limits_n \mathbb P[X=n]=1$

Comment: the summation is up to N or infinity?

Comment: It is across the whole of the support, which your question suggests is $\mathbb{N}^* = \left\{1, 2, 3, \ldots \right\}$ so without an upper limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a simple recursion for $p_n := P(X=n)$ as follows:

- $p_1 = p\underbrace{\sum_{n\geq 1}p_n}_{=1} = p$
- $p_n - p_{n+1} = p\left(\sum_{k\geq n}p_k - \sum_{k\geq n+1}p_k\right) = pp_n\Leftrightarrow p_{n+1} =(1-p)p_n$

All together: $p_1 = p, p_{n+1} = (1-p)p_n \Rightarrow \boxed{p_n = p(1-p)^{n-1}}$

Comment: Okay i think i understand, than if i have N = {0,1,2,...} and P[X=n] = 4/n*P[X=n-1] (is another similar exercise than i have after), the way to reason is the same?

Comment: @Marco : Yes. This is similar. But here you have the unknown probability $p_0 =P(X=0)$. Then, you solve the recursion involving the parameter $p_0$ and use that $\sum_{n\geq 0}p_n = 1$ to determine $p_0$.

Comment: @trancelocation I'm sorry, shouldn't be $p_n = (1-p)^{n-2}$ ?

Comment: @AkaiM : Why should it be like that? If you set $n=1$ in your formula you would get $p_1 > 1$ which cannot be.